# Fast enumeration with RLMResults on large datasets

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm running into an issue where I need to enumerate an RLMResults collection on a relatively large data set (>7,000 items). I get that realm lazily loads its objects as they are accessed, but the issue I run into is that I need to access each of these items in the collection which causes each of the 7,000+ items to be loaded into memory thereby causing an out of memory error. According to the realm documentation they don't support limiting the results of a query.

An example of something I might need to do is to go through and delete files from the file system, and yes I could query using a predicate and only ask for items that are cached, but in a worst case scenario that query could return all items in the library.

```
RLMResults<DLLibrary *> *allItems = [DLLibrary allObjects];
for( DLLibrary *item in allItems ) {
  // My understanding is that once the realm object is ready, it will be
  // lazily loaded into memory. If I have many 1,000's of items in my data
  // store this quickly becomes a problem memory wise.
  if( item.isCached ) {
    [[DLCacheService instance] deleteCachedFileWithDocumentId:item.id];
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be good to see some code or have a clearer idea as to what is going on. Why do you need to access every object, and what are you doing with it once you access it?

Comment: It's really just a simple for-in loop over an RLMResults<> collection. In my case, I retrieve an updated data set from a server and then need to check for items that need to be deleted (e.g. check if current item ID is in data set returned from server, if not then delete the object in realm), but regardless of what I'm doing it could be a calculation that I need to perform on every object. Just looking to see what others have potentially done, or maybe there's something I'm missing.

Comment: It is lazy loaded, so what you can do instead of a for_in is an actually for where you "paginate" the items. You can do a `for 100 times { do things }` and release some memory then repeat this loop until you processed all your realm objects. As long as you don't access a object from the list of objects, it won't really be in memory.

Comment: So just an update on my issue; while I found a work around, I wasn't able to reproduce my issue while fast enumerating over my entire set of records. So my issue was related to something else I was doing. Thank you all who replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to mitigate this would be the use of an `@autoreleasepool` brace to explicitly guarantee the object you lazily-loaded is promptly released once you've finished checking its contents. :)

```
RLMResults<DLLibrary *> *allItems = [DLLibrary allObjects];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < allItems.count; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        DLLibrary *item = allItems[i]; 
        if (item.isCached) {
            [[DLCacheService instance] deleteCachedFileWithDocumentId:item.id];
        }
    }
}
```